# Working with Winforms UI while acquiring data

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, multitasking

I develop Forms Application using C#. This App will collect data from a spectrometer device. When I set continuous acquisition, I am not able to perform other operations during the acquisition happens. I want to zoom the chart and also perform other operations while the acquisition happens. Now when I click zoom button it is only enabling after the acquisition is over. Kindly help me to solve this.

Please see part of code which has a button click to start acquisition. One chart is also getting updated with the values from spectrometer. Also screen shot of UI is at bottom.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            this.Refresh();
            int numberOfPixels; // number of CCD elements
            double[] spectrum;
            spectrum = null;   // spectrometerIndex = 0;

            if (spectrometerIndex == -1)
                return; // no available spectrometer

            numberOfPixels = wrapper.getNumberOfPixels(spectrometerIndex);
            wrapper.setBoxcarWidth(spectrometerIndex, 0);
            wrapper.setCorrectForElectricalDark(spectrometerIndex, 1);
            wrapper.setIntegrationTime(spectrometerIndex, 1000); // acquisition time in microsecs

            int acquiretime = 100;
            if (textBoxin.Text != "")

            {
                int.TryParse(textBoxin.Text, out acquiretime); //arbitrary acquiretime

            }

            Stopwatch integrate = new Stopwatch();
            integrate.Start();
            while (integrate.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(acquiretime))
            {
                this.Refresh();
                spectrum = (double[])wrapper.getSpectrum(spectrometerIndex); data from spectrometer

            }

            integrate.Stop();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are making the UI thread too busy, so it cannot handle UI messages. You need to do non-UI processing in another thread. Consider using async/await when you have something awaitable.

Comment: There area some paths to choose: background workers, asynchronous delegates, threads, async/await or Tasks. But in the end you need to separate the UI code from the process code. It's not a good idea to have long processing methods in event handler code like button_click handlers.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestions. I will try.

Comment: I am not from software background. Doing this for science research. Can anybody please help with some code?